# Reloading individual TableView rows upon changes in document

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Long time listener, first time app developer..

I'm using Firestore data to populate a TableView in Swift 4.2 using a snapshot listener. This works great if I don't mind the entire TableView reloading with every document change, however I've now added animations to the cell that trigger upon a status value change in the document and my present implementation of tableView.reloadData() triggers all cells to play their animations with any change to any document in the collection.

I'm seeking help understanding how to implement reloadRows(at:[IndexPath]) using .documentChanges with diff.type == .modified to reload only the rows that have changed and have spent more time than I'd like to admit trying to figure it out. =/

I have attempted to implement tableView.reloadRows, but cannot seem to understand how to specify the indexPath properly for only the row needing updated. Perhaps I need to add conditional logic for the animations to only execute with changes in the document? Losing hair.. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Snapshot implementation:**

```
    self.listener = query?.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { documents, error in

        guard let snapshot = documents else {

            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")

            return

        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in

            if (diff.type == .added) {

                let source = snapshot.metadata.isFromCache ? "local cache" : "server"

                print("Metadata: Data fetched from \(source)")

                let results = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Task in

                    if let task = Task(eventDictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID) {

                        return task

                    } // if

                    else {

                        fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Task.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")

                    } // else

                } //let results

                self.tasks = results

                self.documents = snapshot.documents

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } // if added

            if (diff.type == .modified) {

                print("Modified document: \(diff.document.data())")

                let results = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Task in

                    if let task = Task(eventDictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID) {

                        return task

                    } // if

                    else {

                        fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Task.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")

                    } // else closure

                } //let closure

                self.tasks = results

                self.documents = snapshot.documents

                self.tableView.reloadData() // <--- reloads the entire tableView with changes = no good

                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: <#T##[IndexPath]#>, with: <#T##UITableView.RowAnimation#>) // <-- is what I need help with

            }

            if (diff.type == .removed) {

                print("Document removed: \(diff.document.data())")

            } // if removed

        } // forEach

    } // listener
```

**cellForRowAt**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventListCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

    let item = tasks[indexPath.row]

    let url = URL.init(string: (item.eventImageURL))
    datas.eventImageURL = url

    cell.eventImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

    cell.eventEntranceLabel!.text = item.eventLocation

    cell.eventTimeLabel!.text = item.eventTime

    if item.eventStatus == "inProgress" {


        cell.eventReponderStatus.isHidden = false

        cell.eventReponderStatus.text = "\(item.eventResponder)" + " is responding"


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow; cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white}, completion: nil)

    }

    else if item.eventStatus == "verifiedOK" {

        cell.eventReponderStatus.isHidden = false

        cell.eventReponderStatus.text = "\(item.eventResponder)" + " verified OK"

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green; cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white}, completion: nil)

    }

    else if item.eventStatus == "sendBackup" {

        cell.eventReponderStatus.isHidden = false

        cell.eventReponderStatus.text = "\(item.eventResponder)" + " needs assistance"

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red; cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white}, completion: nil)
    }

    else if item.eventStatus == "newEvent" {


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red; cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white}, completion: nil)



    }

    else {
        cell.isHidden = true
        cell.eventReponderStatus.isHidden = true

    }


    switch item.eventStatus {

    case "unhandled": cell.eventStatusIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    case "inProgress": cell.eventStatusIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    case "verifiedOK": cell.eventStatusIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    case "sendBackup": cell.eventStatusIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red


    default: cell.eventStatusIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    }

    return cell
}
```

**Variables and setup**

```
// Create documents dictionary
private var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

// Create tasks var
public var tasks: [Task] = []

// Create listener registration var
private var listener : ListenerRegistration!

// Create baseQuery function
fileprivate func baseQuery() -> Query {

    switch switchIndex {
    case 0:
        return Firestore.firestore().collection("metalDetectorData").document("alarmEvents").collection("eventList").limit(to: 50).whereField("eventStatus", isEqualTo: "unhandled")
    case 1:
        return Firestore.firestore().collection("metalDetectorData").document("alarmEvents").collection("eventList").limit(to: 50).whereField("eventStatus", isEqualTo: "verifiedOK")
    case 3:
        return Firestore.firestore().collection("metalDetectorData").document("alarmEvents").collection("eventList").limit(to: 50)
    default:
        return Firestore.firestore().collection("metalDetectorData").document("alarmEvents").collection("eventList").limit(to: 50)//.whereField("eventStatus", isEqualTo: false)
    }

} // baseQuery closure



// Create query variable
fileprivate var query: Query? {
    didSet {
        if let listener = listener {
            listener.remove()

        }
    }
} // query closure
```

**Tasks**

```
struct Task{

    var eventLocation: String
    var eventStatus: String
    var eventTime: String
    var eventImageURL: String
    var eventResponder: String
    var eventUID: String

    var eventDictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "eventLocation": eventLocation,
            "eventStatus": eventStatus,
            "eventTime": eventTime,
            "eventImageURL": eventImageURL,
            "eventResponder": eventResponder,
            "eventUID": eventUID
            ]
    } // eventDictionary


} // Task

extension Task{
    init?(eventDictionary: [String : Any], id: String) {
        guard let eventLocation = eventDictionary["eventLocation"] as? String,
              let eventStatus = eventDictionary["eventStatus"] as? String,
              let eventTime = eventDictionary["eventTime"] as? String,
              let eventImageURL = eventDictionary["eventImageURL"] as? String,
              let eventResponder = eventDictionary["eventResponder"] as? String,
              let eventUID = id as? String

            else { return nil }

        self.init(eventLocation: eventLocation, eventStatus: eventStatus, eventTime: eventTime, eventImageURL: eventImageURL, eventResponder: eventResponder, eventUID: eventUID)


    }
}
```

Comment: Is `self.documents` an array that you use to populate the table view?

Comment: Hi, theMikeSwan, thanks for reaching out. I edited the post with contextual code containing the declaration of related objects/vars. Thanks!

Comment: How do `Tasks` and `DocumentSnapshot`s relate to one another? You use `DocumentSnapshot`s in your listener and `Task`s in your cell for row method.

Comment: tasks["key", "value"] is populated with [Task]. I added that code too just now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The table view update methods like `reloadRows` needs an array of index paths pointing to the cells that should be updated. Typically this in done by calling `index(of: )` on the array containing all of the table data. You get the index of each item that needs to be updated in the table view, create an `IndexPath` for each one, and stick them all in an array.  The table view will then call `cellForRowAt` to get the new cell. The second argument specifies what kind of animation you want it to use. You will need to experiment with the options to find the one you want in your case.

Comment: Given that the contents of `tasks` is where the cells get their data and that you want to update cells based on changes to the contents of `documents` you will need to devise a way to map between the two.

Comment: Also, as a note on table view cells, it is better to have `cellForRowAt` give the cell the item it should display and let the cell take care of all the particulars. Most new developers do it the way you have but it makes `cellForRowAt` harder to read down the road.

Comment: I sincerely hope to get on your level someday with continued exposure, and again appreciate the continues responses. If I'm understanding correctly, I need a value to map an index with. Since eventDictionary contains both key:value pairs from the response data and ", id: String" containing the documentID from Firestore, would it be possible to use the stored Firebase documentID of the dictionary entries to form an index to work with? If so, could you suggest a method for using that, purdy please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did this without really knowing Firebase or having a compiler to check for errors. There may be some typos and you may have to do some unwrapping and casting but the idea should be there. I added lots of comments to help you understand what is happening in the code…

```
self.listener = query?.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { documents, error in

    guard let snapshot = documents else {

        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")

        return

    }

    // You only need to do this bit once, not for every update
    let source = snapshot.metadata.isFromCache ? "local cache" : "server"

    print("Metadata: Data fetched from \(source)")

    let results = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Task in

        if let task = Task(eventDictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID) {

            return task

        } // if

        else {

            fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Task.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")

        } // else

    } //let results

    // Tell the table view you are about to give it a bunch of updates that should all get batched together
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in

        let section = 0 // This should be whatever section the update is in. If you only have one section then 0 is right.

        if (diff.type == .added) {
            // If a document has been added we need to insert a row for it…
            // First we filter the results from above to find the task connected to the document ID.
            // We use results here because the document doesn't exist in tasks yet.
            let filteredResults = results.filter { $0.eventUID == diff.document.documentID }
            // Do some saftey checks on the filtered results
            if filteredResults.isEmpty {
                // Deal with the fact that there is a document that doesn't have a companion task in results. This shouldn't happen, but who knows…
            }
            if filteredResults.count > 1 {
                // Deal with the fact that either the document IDs aren't terribly unique or that a task was added more than once for the saem document
            }
            let row = results.index(of: filteredResults[0])
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)

            // Tell the table view to insert the row
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        } // if added

        if (diff.type == .modified) {
            // For modifications we need to get the index out of tasks so the index path matches the current path not the one it will have after the updates.
            let filteredTasks = self.tasks.filter { $0.eventUID == diff.document.documentID }
            // Do some saftey checks on the filtered results
            if filteredTasks.isEmpty {
                // Deal with the fact that there is a document that doesn't have a companion task in results. This shouldn't happen, but who knows…
            }
            if filteredTasks.count > 1 {
                // Deal with the fact that either the document IDs aren't terribly unique or that a task was added more than once for the saem document
            }
           let row = self.tasks.index(of: filteredTasks[0])
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)

        // Tell the table view to update the row
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    }

    if (diff.type == .removed) {

        print("Document removed: \(diff.document.data())")

        // For deleted documents we need to use tasks since it doesn't appear in results
        let filteredTasks = self.tasks.filter { $0.eventUID == diff.document.documentID }
        // Do some saftey checks on the filtered results
        if filteredTasks.isEmpty {
            // Deal with the fact that there is a document that doesn't have a companion task in results. This shouldn't happen, but who knows…
        }
        if filteredTasks.count > 1 {
            // Deal with the fact that either the document IDs aren't terribly unique or that a task was added more than once for the saem document
        }
        let row = self.tasks.index(of: filteredTasks[0])
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        // ** Notice that the above few lines are very similiar in all three cases. The only thing that varies is our use results or self.tasks. You can refactor this out into its own method that takes the array to be filtered and the documentID you are looking for. It could then return either the the row number by itself or the whole index path (returning just the row would be more flexible).

        // Tell the table view to remove the row
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    } // if removed

    } // forEach

    // Sync tasks and documents with the new info
    self.tasks = results

    self.documents = snapshot.documents

    // Tell the table view you are done with the updates so It can make all the changes
     self.tableView.endUpdates()

} // listener
```

Comment: Dude! Thanks for taking the time to help me make sense of this. I really appreciate this.

Comment: Back at this view controller today. I hesitated asking since you've already provided so much support, but idk what else to do. I was getting an error with the "let row" not being happy in Swift 4.2, so I changed it to "let row = results.index(where: { $0.eventUID == diff.document.documentID })" and errors went away, however every time I try to build I get a compiler error saying " cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Task' " but it doesn't highlight any line to indicate where to troubleshoot.  Honest to God, I'd like to send you a Starbucks gift card for all your help :D

Comment: Disregard. I'm an idiot, it was a different view controller throwing the error. your solution works BEAUTIFULLY. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your change listener all you really need to do is save the indexes of the corresponding changes, save your model objects, and then trigger your table view updates.

```
let insertions = snapshot.documentChanges.compactMap {
    return $0.type == .added ? IndexPath(row: Int($0.newIndex), section: 0) : nil
}
let modifications = snapshot.documentChanges.compactMap {
    return $0.type == .modified ? IndexPath(row: Int($0.newIndex), section: 0) : nil
}
let deletions = snapshot.documentChanges.compactMap {
    return $0.type == .removed ? IndexPath(row: Int($0.oldIndex), section: 0) : nil
}

self.userDocuments = snapshot.documents
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertions, with: .automatic)
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications, with: .automatic)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions, with: .automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

There are more efficient ways of mapping the changes to IndexPaths but this was the clearest way to write it.